# Invalidate the Java session for new tab

Tags: java, session

How to invalidate a session when I click new tab window for same application(for same url)? Once I access the same url the existing session has opened. I want start different session for

Comment: Invalidate only for the new tab?. What if I go back to my previous open tab? Should the session exist?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to the session/cookie, browsers currently don't support separate cookies for each different tab/window.

But, some frameworks have this concept of Window so that using it you can be notified when a new window/tab is opened. Once you can detect it you can destroy the old windows. Updating the session (or invalidating and creating a new one) won't have the desired effect (even if you can do this) on the other tab as this whole thing might repeat when the user goes to the other old tab.

Your best bet is to keep multiple windows for the user in a single session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple servlet you can use following code,

```
// Get the existing session. 
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); 

  // Invalidate the existing session. 
 if(session!=null) { 
    session.invalidate(); 
 }
```

You can call this servlet by doing mapping for your new tab url in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use Url rewriting for different sessions in different tabs/windows.  If you want to invalidate the session, then just remove all previous sessions for that user. The only problem would be if someone copied and pasted the url. If this could be a problem, then look into somehow storing the session key in HTML5 storage.

Answer (score -1):

Session ID is kept in a cookie, so you cannot have two different sessions for the same application in one browser (a new tab or a new window - doesn't matter) at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Your server session is mapped with the HTTP Session. You can not have two HTTP sessions at the same time in the same browser... And how would you identify that the has pressed Open in New Tab and he didn't open the link in the same tab? You should have an AJAX ping for that (pretty tricky...)